# Can't establish TCP connection in the same machine by using assigned physical IP address

Tags: tcp, tcpclient

I faced a weird issue that the TCP connection couldn't establish in the same machine by using the assigned physical IP address.

I noticed the issue because my third party software like HornetQ can't establish TCP connection to its JMS server from its local JMS client in the same machine.

Thus I wrote a simple Java testing program to narrow down root cause. Then I found that if the TCP server open any port by using the assigned physical IP address, the TCP client can't connect to the server by using the same IP address and port.

However, if I use the lookback IP address instead of the assigned physical IP address in the TCP client, it then can connect to TCP server.

I'm very confuse now cause my network engineer said if the TCP connection trying to establish is in the same machine, it should not be any network issue since the package didn't go out the box.

Is it possible that the network card of the machine (the machine is a HP server) spoilt ? Thank you for your time and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If a TCP server is bound to a specific local IP:Port, a local client *CAN* connect to that same local IP:Port just fine. Worse case, you *may* have to explicitly bind the client to the same IP before connecting to the server, in case the OS tries to make the client use a different default IP that does not have a route to the server's IP.  However, a decent OS should be smart enough to recognize the destination IP is local and make sure to use that same IP when binding the client implicitly.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, thank you for your reply. The binding you mentioned above, can you be more specific. Is it achieve through update the host file in local machine or other way around ?

Comment: I'm referring to calling the socket API `bind()` function before calling the `connect()` function. `bind()` tells the socket which local IP:Port to use. In Java terms, the local IP:Port is bound to using the overloaded [`Socket()`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.InetAddress, int, java.net.InetAddress, int)) constructor that has `localAddr` and `localPort` parameters, or the [`Socket.bind()`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#bind(java.net.SocketAddress)) method.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, thanks a lot for the explanation. Got your point and the issue have been resolved. The root cause is due to the security department turn on some security policies to disallow the port connection.